# How can I post JSON to an ASP.NET controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, post

How can I post JSON to an ASP.NET MVC controller action?

### sample scenario

An external authentication system requires JSON be posted to it.  I would like to capture the user's credentials on my site and forward them as JSON to the authentication site.  Redirects are not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we'll use `http://www.example.com/ExtAuth/Login` as our fictitious external authentication endpoint.

ExtAuth will expect us to post a JSON string representing an object with two properties: `User`, and `Password`.

ExtAuth will return a JSON string representing an object with two properties: `Status`, and `Message`.

### The key to making this whole thing work is the **`extRequest.ContentType`**.  It **MUST** be set to *`application/json`*.

I'll leave proper error handling as an exercise to the user.

```
<HttpPost>
<AllowAnonymous>
Public Function Login(ByVal model As LoginModel) As ActionResult
  Dim authEndpointUrl As String = "http://www.example.com/ExtAuth/Login"
  Dim result As String = String.Empty  ' this will hold the JSON returned from ExtAuth
  Dim resultModel As LoginResult = Nothing  ' The deserialized form of the result JSON
  Dim data As String = String.Empty  ' the serialized representation of our login data

  Dim extRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(authEndpointUrl)
      extRequest.Method = "POST"
      extRequest.ContentType = "application/json"

  data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)
  Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(extRequest.GetRequestStream)
    writer.Write(data)
  End Using

  Using extResponse As HttpWebResponse = extRequest.GetResponse
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(extResponse.GetResponseStream)
      result = reader.ReadToEnd
    End Using
  End Using

  resultModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LoginResult)(result)
  ViewData("Status") = resultModel.Status
  ViewData("Message") = resultModel.Message

  Return View(model)

End Function
```

This method should work for MVC 3+.

Comment: @AndrewCounts Answering your own question is not forbidden: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer